# fancybox v2 div click in title

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, title

I have the following in fancybox 2 as per instructions:

```
afterLoad: function() {
    this.title = '<center><a href="js/download.php?file=' + '../' +  this.href + '">Download</a></center>';
}
```

Now, would it be possible to call a function from the title? Something like:

```
afterLoad: function() {
    this.title = '<center><div id="loadMore">Click</div></center>';
}
```

and

```
$('#loadMore').click(function(){
alert("hi ");
});
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be possible if you bind the `click` event in a *delegated* form.

You could use the `.on()` method this way:

```
$(document).on("click", "#loadMore", function () {
    alert("hi");
});
```

that will bind a `click` event to the selector `#loadMore` regardless it exists or it's added in the future (like it happens in your `afterLoad` callback) to the DOM.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g8ze0cxp/)**